# How to use lame to encode to MP3 in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, lame

I know there were a few questions about this topic before, but nun of there seem to have the full answer.

I'm  trying to encode AFF to MP3, found that the only free way is to use "LAME". unfortunately it has only support in mac, so i get linker errors when trying to use it in a IOS project.

Did anyone managed to use this library for this use? 
Any help would be much appreciated, its very important for me..

Comment: Is your problem in compiling the library for iOS or using it?

Comment: Compiling the library for IOS

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the library `libmp3lame` using autoconf.  I use the following bash script to set up the parameters for `configure`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# The device's architecture
export ARCH="armv7-apple-darwin12"

# SDK setup
export SDKVER="7.1"
export SDKROOT="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk"

export PREFIX="/tmp/iphone-$SDKVER-armv7"

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$SDKROOT/usr/lib/pkgconfig":"$PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig"

# Flags
export CPPFLAGS="-arch armv7 -isysroot $SDKROOT -I$PREFIX/include"
export CFLAGS="-std=gnu99"
export CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++"
export LDFLAGS="-arch armv7 -isysroot $SDKROOT -L$PREFIX/lib"

# Run configure 
./configure \
        --prefix="$PREFIX" \
        --host="$ARCH" \
        --enable-static \
        --disable-shared $@
```

If you save the code above to `ios-configure.sh` in LAME's source directory you can then  configure and compile wih the following commands:

```
% ./ios-configure.sh
% make libmp3lame
```

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. Second, i'm sorry maybe i wasn't clear enough with my question, i'm trying to make a lib file of  libmp3lame compile for IOS, do you happen to know how to do that?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to explain with my answer.  Once you have the LAME 3.99 source code you can use the shell code above to configure it properly for compilation.

Comment: Yes i have the source code, but i not sure what is the right of using your shell code for configuration, could you be enough to link some guidelines for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <lame/lame.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

const int PCM_SIZE = 4096;
const int MP3_SIZE = 4096;

@interface AudioFile : NSObject

-(BOOL) encode: (float*) recordedData
     datasize : (int) size
    sampleRate: (int) nSampleRate
       docName: (char*) fileName;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END




#import "AudioFile.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation AudioFile

short int pcm_buffer_I_L[PCM_SIZE];
short int pcm_buffer_I_R[PCM_SIZE];
unsigned char mp3buf[MP3_SIZE];

-(BOOL) encode: (float*) recordedData // Float Array
     datasize : (int) size            // Size of Float Array
    sampleRate: (int) nSampleRate     // Sample rate
       docName: (char*) fileName      // File Name
{
    NSString *file = [NSString stringWithCString:fileName encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSString *tmpUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), file];

    NSLog(@"Mp3 File Path: %@", tmpUrl);

    float write;

    //Converting into mp3, so we need the mp3 file ready!
    FILE *mp3 = fopen((char*)[tmpUrl UTF8String], "wb");

    lame_t lame = lame_init();
    lame_set_in_samplerate(lame, nSampleRate);
    lame_set_out_samplerate(lame, nSampleRate);
    lame_set_VBR(lame, vbr_max_indicator);
    lame_set_mode(lame, MONO); //if this is enabled the channels will be set to 1 by default
    //    lame_set_num_channels(lame, 1);
    lame_set_quality(lame, 0); //0 is the best .. 9 is the worst
    lame_init_params(lame);

    NSLog(@"Sample Rate: %d " , lame_get_in_samplerate(lame));

    /*
     lame_encode_buffer_interleaved_ieee_float
     1st pram = lame config
     2nd pram = float
     3rd pram = frame
     4th pram = mp3buf //mp3buf is an array of unsigned char with size of 4096
     5th pram = size of Mp3 which is 4096
     */

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        write = lame_encode_buffer_interleaved_ieee_float(lame, &recordedData[i], 1, mp3buf, MP3_SIZE);

        fwrite(mp3buf, write, 1, mp3);
    }

    lame_close(lame);

    fclose(mp3);

    return YES;
}

@end
```

You could use my git link. the code is in Objective C

https://gitlab.com/a.raza/lame-encoder-and-decoder-for-ios-unity-plugin

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)